# Entity Framework Core migrations compatibility

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I know that Entity Framework migrations aren't compatible with Entity Framework Core, but I could not find a statement clarifying whether Entity Framework Core migrations are guaranteed to be compatible with all future versions of Entity Framework Core. Is there any such statement?

Comment: I could not find any statement, but that is the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  But EF -> EF Core was a rewrite, with lots of breaking changes.  There is nothing like that planned for the future.

But worst-case scenario you would need to [Reset All Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#resetting-all-migrations).

Comment: That is, I'd have to programmatically migrate to a new database, because it's embedded in the application and has to support updates from all existing versions. Not exactly fun, but fine if it's improbable.